# default value selection in bootstrap multiselect search bar not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

This question already asked, but it is not solve my issue

Am tying to use [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) in my project.

When I use default value selection in bootstrap multiselect search bar not showing

demo https://jsfiddle.net/xctpL8am/2/

> If am not using `$('#example-getting-started').multiselect('select', ['1', '3'],{....});` in `drop-down` search bar not showing.

> If am using `$('#example-getting-started').multiselect({....});` in `drop-down` search bar showing.

I want to show search bar with default value selection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-getting-started').multiselect('select', ['1', '3'],{
      includeSelectAllOption: false,
      enableFiltering: true,
      includeFilterClearBtn: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true
    });
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/css/prettify.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/js/prettify.js"></script>


<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Sunday</option>
    <option value="2">Monday</option>
    <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="5">Thursday</option>
    <option value="6">Friday</option>
    <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the constructor syntax you're using for the library is incorrect; you cannot initialise the library *and* set the selected options at the same time.

The [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) suggests that you should initialise the plugin on your object and then set the selected options in a separate call - see the `select` method in the previous link.

Using this method means that the Search box is displayed correctly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $select = $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeFilterClearBtn: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true
  });

  $select.multiselect('select', ['1', '3']);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/css/prettify.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/js/prettify.js"></script>


<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Sunday</option>
  <option value="2">Monday</option>
  <option value="3">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="4">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="5">Thursday</option>
  <option value="6">Friday</option>
  <option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select>
```